# use require to dynamically assign variable to global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-webkit

I'm building an modular app and have a configuration file to include different modules depending on user preferences.

Normally I'd do something like

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

but I'm taking the required modules from an array, so for each require I have a script object that looks like this

```
{
   name:'fs',
   file:'fs',
   isGlobal:true
}
```

then I'm dynamically requesting the module with

```
window[script.name] = require(script.file);
```

this works fine if I check for `window.fs`. However, other modules that rely on `fs` will call just `fs`.

I know `window.fs` and `fs` should both resolve, but in node-webkit, they aren't.

I'm trying to figure out a way to include the `var name` as a global directly.

Of course, I can't use `var script.name = require(script.file);` as that would set the script.name value, not a global variable.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Sounds like you should just use Browserify, rather than creating your own thing here, which is what it looks like

Comment: For global variables you should always have a global namespace in your main script. Assign all such variables to this namespace so they can be accessed throughout the application.

Comment: @unmair can you explain how you would use that while incorporating other modules which don't use the global namespace?

Comment: @jsantell I'm not a massive fan of Browserify, and even if I were to use it, how would I use it to dynamically include modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: it's been a few versions since I've last used node-webkit, but I think the below is still accurate. I tend to abbreviate node-webkit to nw, if that's okay. :)

> I know window.fs and fs should both resolve, but in node-webkit, they aren't.

In nw, `global` is the global object, while each nw window has it's own `window` object (unless you fork nw). This may be a lil bit confusing, since using the nw devtools to create a global will actually create a property on `window` as expected, so it's not unreasonable to assume you can create globals the same way as in a browser. However, that's really just a side-effect of the devtools running in nw's window context.

However, code running in nw's module context does not even have access to `window` but can, of course, access `global` normally.

This is documented [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts). The first three paragraphs specifically deal with your issue. In short, you'll want to be sure which context your code is running in.

Node's globals meanwhile have a (brief) description [here](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to global in cross env way:

```
var global = new Function("return this")();
global.fs = require('fs');
```

Then at any point you can refer to fs module via simple global `fs` variable, and in browser environment `global` would be `window`.

Still, you should reconsider your approach. As above is very poor way to work with CJS style. One of the beauties of CJS is that it allows you not to rely on global scope, and you go against that, which raise issues.

Other thing, it's a bad practice to resolve paths passed to require dynamically. In modules that we'll have soon with ES6 it won't be possible, you should always use plain strings, and it's good practice to follow with CJS as well. It would be more future bulletproof if you generate script that injects plain strings to requires.

Comment: thanks for all your feedback. I'm not sure how I would resolve the issue with require only accepting plain strings if different clients are going to be loading different modules. I'll have to take a closer look at that.